# Use header/footer written in php from a portal in a website written in asp.net mvc

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

How to integrate a web site written in asp.net mvc into a web portal written in php? I need to keep only the header/footer from php site. Both of them will have separate hosting and we want to keep the links (SEO) so the iframe is not a solution. Maybe a web service to get static HTML? Any ideas?

Comment: This is mainly an ASP.net question, I'd recommend you to change the title to reflect that, to appropriate attention.

Comment: Are you looking to extract specific info from the ASP site or just as it-is?

Comment: I want to extract the header and footer which are written in php

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use an `<iframe>` another possibility would be to have the PHP site send an HTTP request to the ASP.NET MVC site, retrieve the HTML and include it into the response. But you might need to adapt your ASP.NET MVC site so that it no longer uses a Layout to avoid getting multiple heads and bodies into the resulting markup.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by processing the HTML code in ASP.NET and modify the desired section. 
I used HtmlAgilityPack to parse the HTML code.